# mutek usb smartcard reader not detected(Probably missing drivers)

Tags: raspbian, usb

Recently i re-started fiddling around with smart card readers and raspberry pi.
A few months ago when i started to fiddleing around with usb smartcard readers and raspberry pi, i was doing some testing/reading with readers like Konig CMP-SMARTRW10 and a HID reader and i dont remember installing any drivers or something similar, i did install pscs lib from Ludovic Rousseau, and i manage to get it working.

I recently pick up this project with some new readers, in this case mutek mtk-pt3901-2(http://www.mutek.com/pt39013902-half-insertion-pcsc-ic-card-reader/), and i am trying to make it work,but the card reader is not being detected.
when i run pcsc_scan,it is saying "Scanning present readers...Waiting for the first reader..."
but when i do lsusb it showes that there is something connected to the usb  , but it does not show any details..
it appears as "Bus 001 Device 006: ID 4143:3901 ".
This manufacter id and device id doesnt appear in libccid_info.plist..
What could be the problem? missing drivers?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This seems to be the product of a Chinese Company [ACT](http://www.card-readerwriter.com/sell-1309306-manual-ic-card-reader-writer-act-pt-3901-2-kiosk-parking-gaming.html) and there is little in the way of product details available - though that site reports a head life of 100K not 300K card passes...! It professes a USB(PC/SC) protocol and there does seem to be material relating to that out on the Internet (and you mention a pscs lib) - it *may* be as simple as getting that USB id recognised as a suitable device or much harder needing work with the coder of that library to add support.

Answer (score 1):

i manage to get it working, and it was a much simpler solution that i thought.
What i did was add the add the manufactor id and device id to the file liccid_info_plist.
In order to get these values what i did was issue the command lsusb to get the manufactor and device id in this case 4143 abd 3901, and add the sto the file libccid_info.plist, and restart the raspberry.
After restart by issue the command lsub we can see the smart card reader with the name we stated on libccid_info.plist, and by doing pcsc_scan the smart card reader is detected and it uploads info from the card to the screen.
I dont know if this is the best way, but i manage to get it working.